# What is the difference between these git diff commands?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am on a branch, `br`, which is pushed as `origin/br`, on which I've made several several commits. In the case where `HEAD` == `br` == `origin/br`, I am running these two commands:

```
(1) git diff <some-commit>
```

and

```
(2) git diff <some-commit> HEAD origin/br
```

where `HEAD` is a direct descendant from `<some-commit>`

The two give different results, and while I understand that what `(1)` does I have no idea what `(2)` is printing. What does `(2)` do? I believe it has something to do with this entry from the man page, but I do not know what it means:

> ```
>    <path>...
>        The <paths> parameters, when given, are used to limit the diff to the named 
>        paths (you can give directory names and get diff for all files under
>        them).
> ```

Comment: What is `abcdef`? Does it refer to a commit? I can't make sense of your second command. The closest `git-diff` syntax I can think of is `git diff <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]`...

Comment: Could you share what the two commands are printing?

Comment: @Jubobs Yeah, it's a specific commit.

Comment: @jthill No :) But (1) prints a lines prefixed with either `-` or `+`... but (2) prints them with `--` or `++`... but backwards from what (1) printed.

Comment: @Barry If you don't give us at least a glimpse of the outputs of (1) and (2), any attempt at answering this question pretty much amounts to reading tea leaves...

Comment: Is your working directory or index dirty? (`git status`)

Comment: @AndrewC Completely clean.

Comment: Note that normally you would not specify 3 SHAs as you have, but it appears that when you do you trigger this ` Any diff-generating command can take the \u2018-c\u2018 or --cc option to produce a combined diff when showing a merge.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting the output is showing you `diff -cc $pathname` and `index $sha1,$sha2..$sha3` where sometimes two of sha's 1,2,3 are the same, and from some quick digging I think git's probably treating one of the commits (the middle, it looks like) as an explicit merge base, the other two as explicit merge tips -- but according to this from `builtin/diff.c` the arguments you're passing are not correct.

```
/*
 * We could get N tree-ish in the rev.pending_objects list.
 * Also there could be M blobs there, and P pathspecs.
 *
 * N=0, M=0:
 *  cache vs files (diff-files)
 * N=0, M=2:
 *      compare two random blobs.  P must be zero.
 * N=0, M=1, P=1:
 *  compare a blob with a working tree file.
 *
 * N=1, M=0:
 *      tree vs cache (diff-index --cached)
 *
 * N=2, M=0:
 *      tree vs tree (diff-tree)
 *
 * N=0, M=0, P=2:
 *      compare two filesystem entities (aka --no-index).
 *
 * Other cases are errors.
 */
```